# I can't unpack data in my pyodbc output converter

Tags: python, converters, pyodbc

I am not sure how to use struct.unpack to see the data in the bytearray that is sent in because the data is not coming in a fixed manner. It is a variable length packed decimal format, terminated by hex character. The data type is SQL_DECIMAL.

For example, if I am expecting a 123, I see the bytearray values printed as \x12\x3e......

I am using Python 3.4.3, pyodbc 4.0.1 on Win 7

Comment: So 1234 would be `\x12\x34` and 12345 would be `\x12\x34\x5e`?

Comment: Yes. 1234 would be \x12\x34\xe0.
BTW, I wrote code to parse the nybbles, but I want something pythonic.

Comment: The byte arrays I'm getting (pyodbc, Windows) look different. E.g. for Decimal('1.000000') I'm getting 'b'\x07\x06\x01@B\x0f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this qualifies as "pars[ing] the nybbles" or is "pythonic" enough for you, but this seems to work:

```python
import itertools


def convert_packed_decimal(byte_stream):
    digit_list = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([[(b & 0xF0) >> 4, b & 0xF] for b in byte_stream]))
    num_digits = digit_list.index(0xE)
    return sum([digit_list[i] * 10 ** (num_digits - i - 1) for i in range(num_digits)])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(convert_packed_decimal(b'\x12\x34\xe0'))
    print(convert_packed_decimal(b'\x90\x21\x0e'))
```

For test data `b'\x12\x34\xe0'`, the first line of the function uses a list comprehension to extract the individual digits in a nested list

```python
[[1,2],[3,4],[14,0]]
```

and then `list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(...` flattens it out into a simple list.

```python
[1,2,3,4,14,0]
```

The second line finds the index of the `0xE` (decimal 14) terminator, giving us the number of digits to process (4, in this case).

The third line uses a list comprehension to process each digit, multiplying it by the power of 10 corresponding to its position in the list,

```python
[1 * 1000, 2 * 100, 3 * 10, 4 * 1]
```

and then `sum(...` adds them up.